# Delete dynamicaly created folder name in Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to delete Jenikns workspace using Include pattern. I would like to delete a folder Folder_name. If i write Folder_name to Include field it is correctly deleted, but if i write ${Foldern} which stores Folder_name the workspace\Folder_name is not deleted. Any idea how can it be accomplished?

Comment: Where are you setting `Foldern=Folder_name`?

Comment: Please provide at least the full line of code, so it is possible to know what you are currently trying.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ${Foldern}:-

Try

> $Foldern **(without parenthesis)**

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't work as well :/ I did a workaround deleting folder through a batch command in the beginning of processing.

Comment: you can check whether Foldern has any value by  "echo $Foldern" (may be the value is not assigned)